# Call public function from class that implements an exported interface from another file in typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, import

How do I import function from a typescript interface?

In the example below, how to call `foo` from another file?

```
namesapce a{
  export interface b{
     foo():number;
 }
 class c implements b{
     public foo():number{...}
 }
}
```

I tried with `import =` and `import require` and `import {} from as` but nothing works.

I get `not a module` and `imported type used as a value` but from the solutions I see it seems like I need to add an export or change code that I cannot change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use `import` or `export` here. The instance method `foo` belongs to the class `c`, which is a member of the [namespace](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/namespaces.html) `a` inside the global script scope (so the file is not a module).

Also `c` as containing class is not exported, so `foo` is not public as well. The only namespace member available is interface `b`, which just contains type declarations for `c` and no implementation (`b` will be erased at runtime).

In general, a namespace `a` inside the script scope can be used like this (no import):

```
a.c; // implicit global
window.a.c; // (explicit window global)
globalThis.a.c // environment independent global (e.g. for node and browser)
```

Assuming, you want to use namespaces and change the export of `c`, `foo` can be invoked with following code snippet - paste that into a file without `import`/`export` at top-level:

```
namespace a {
  export interface b {
    foo(): number;
  }
  export class c implements b {
    public foo(): number {
      return 42;
    }
  }
}

const cInstance = new a.c()
cInstance.foo()
```

Answer (score 0):

Even though `Namespaces are simply named JavaScript objects in the global namespace.` from typescript [documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/namespaces-and-modules.html) you can revise your code and use it as follows (let's say this code exists in namespace-a.ts file)
Example 1:

```
export namespace a {
  export interface b {
    foo(): number;
  }

  export class c implements b {
    public foo(): number {
      console.log('calling foo from class c');
      return 123;
    }
  }
}
```

and in another file you can import it like this

`import * as namespaceA from '../location-to-file/namespace-a';`

and in your code you can use it like following:

```
let testVar = new namespaceA.a.c();
testVar.foo();
```

NOTE: The above is considered a bad practice if you read [this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/namespaces-and-modules.html#pitfalls-of-namespaces-and-modules) from the documentation.

> To reiterate why you shouldn’t try to namespace your module contents, the general idea of namespacing is to provide logical grouping of constructs and to prevent name collisions. Because the module file itself is already a logical grouping, and its top-level name is defined by the code that imports it, it’s unnecessary to use an additional module layer for exported objects.

You should just revise your code as follows. In your file fileBC.ts:

Example 2:

```
export interface b {
  foo(): number;
}

export class c implements b {
  public foo(): number {
    console.log('calling foo from class c');
    return 1;
  }
}
```

and in another file use it as follows:

`import * as fileBC from '../location-to-file/fileBC';`

```
let testVar = new fileBC.c();
testVar.foo();
```

P.S.: Sorry for the bad names I use for files and variables but you can get the point. I hate my variable naming. I hope it helped.